# Генерация случайного числа, подчиненного некоторому условию. Как сделать?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Знаю, что можно генерировать числа с помощью:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random ();
```

Но если я хочу не просто случайное число в указанном диапазоне, а случайное число, которое подчинено некоторому условию? **Вот такой пример:** как получить случайное число, которое делится без остатка на переменную **dividend**? Первое, что пришло в голову, так это просто перечислять все случайные числа до тех пор, пока не найдем нужное. Как-то так:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random ();
int dividend = randomGenerator.Next (10, 1000);
int divisor;

do {
    divisor = randomGenerator.Next (1, dividend + 1);
} while (dividend % divisor != 0)
```

Но это получается много лишней работы. А если условие более специфичное и вероятность получения нужного нам числа случайным подбором будет крайне мала? Тогда это, по идее, должно вызывать подлагивания (небольшим программам это, конечно, не грозит, ибо компы сейчас мощные). Но если, того хуже, такого числа вообще не будет? Тогда программа зависнет. С этим я сейчас и столкнулся, пока решал эту задачу.

Как оказалось, я получил простое число (делится только на 1 и на себя), а внутри цикла, забыв про простые числа, сначала почему-то решил написать:

```
divisor = randomGenerator.Next (10, dividend);
```

**Но суть не в этой ошибке. А в том, как генерировать случайные числа, подчиненные некоторому условию?** *(и получить с первого выполнения функции подходящий под условие результат... без лишнего перебора, который зазря нагружает компьютер)*

Comment: > как получить случайное число, которое делится без остатка на переменную dividend?

В каком диапазоне  должны быть числа?

Comment: @sp7 От 1/10 исходного числа до 1/2 этого числа. И да... Пока этого нет, но я в будущем позабочусь, чтобы исходным числом не могло быть простое число.

Comment: @JerryGreen, а исходные числа чем-нибудь ограничены, в каком они могут быть диапазоне?

Comment: @sp7 Для данной задачи не столь важно. Скажем, 1000. Мне стало интересно возможно ли вообще как-то генерировать числа, сразу подходящие под условия, без необходимости перебора.

Comment: @JerryGreen в конкретной данной задаче: 

    нижний предел - (число / 10) / dividend
    верхний предел - (число / 2) / dividend
    искомое число - рандом (нижний предел, верхний предел) * dividend

Если нужны обязательно целые числа, то, возможно, придется немного поиграть с пределами.

Comment: >Для данной задачи не столь важно 

ну вообще-то это важно - не каждый алгоритм будет удовлетворительно работать   на диапазоне в 4 миллиарда значений точно так же как на диапазоне в сотню значений

Comment: @Etki сделал так. Нижний и верхний предел почему-то обращаются в ноль. Хотя dividend там не равен нулю. Я так понимаю это какая-то белеберда с типами. У меня все типы стоят как int. Я еще нов в C#, не подскажете в чем дело?

Comment: @JerryGreen, вы наверняка приводите это к int. А надо double.  
И ещё попробуйте вместо 10 написать 10.0

Comment: @Dazar еще до вашего совета попробовал тип Double - безуспешно. Но вот написать 10.0 вместо 10 (в совокупности с типом Double) - это реально помогло. Сам не додумался. Хотя главная суть во время всей этой дискуссии утерялась (выделено жирным в описании), но все равно спасибо :)

Comment: @JerryGreen, может быть, я не до конца понял Вашу задачу. Но, если бы ее решал я, то первое же сгенерированное случайное число просто умножил бы на dividend и произведение считал бы результатом.

Comment: Может я конечно чего-то не понял, но что мешает результат Random.Next() умножать каждый раз на этот dividend и результат возвращать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае — никак.

Представьте себе, что это было бы можно. Тогда вы смогли бы написать программу, которая даёт случайное число `X` такое, что найдутся `Y` и `Z`, удовлетворяющие соотношению

```
X^n + Y^n = Z^n
```

Таким образом вы смогли бы легко доказать или опровергнуть Великую теорему Ферма!

---

В конкретных случая иногда можно переформулировать задачу, чтобы она имела решение. Например, для случайного целого числа из диапазона `[a, b]`, делящегося на `N`, можно просто взять случайное число из диапазона `[ceil(a/N), floor(b/N)]`, и умножить его на `N`.

Comment: @VladD На всё то у вас найдется ответ :)

Только вы, похоже, и поняли главную суть моего вопроса. Ваш ответ позволил мне очень хорошенько задуматься. Заодно узнал про Великую теорему Ферма :)

Похоже, и правда не может быть такой универсальной функции, которая генерировала бы случайное число под любое нужное условие. Под свое условие - своя функция (а точнее, свои параметры). А под некоторые условия и вовсе никакая функция не подойдет :)

Большое спасибо!

Comment: @JerryGreen: Пожалуйста! Весьма польщён!